# Unable to start my Postgres database after adding pgaudit on my shared_preload_libraries

Tags: database, postgresql, oraclelinux, pgaudit

I am getting these errors (please see below) after I restart my psql database.
This occurs after i install pgaudit and adding pgaudit on my postgresql.conf.
I wonder what am i missing, is it a problem on pgaudit installation?

```
2024-01-22 10:00:21.293 PST [3212773] FATAL:  58P01: could not access file "pgaudit": No such file or directory
2024-01-22 10:00:21.293 PST [3212773] LOCATION:  internal_load_library, dfmgr.c:210
```

pgaudit rpm

```
yum list pgaudit
Last metadata expiration check: 0:29:17 ago on Mon 22 Jan 2024 09:50:21 AM PST.
Installed Packages
pgaudit.x86_64                                                                 1.7.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90110+d8a562d5       

rpm -qa | grep pgaudit
pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90110+d8a562d5.x86_64
```

OS details:

Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 8.6
Kernel: Linux 5.4.17-2136.310.7.el8uek.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

psql version
psql (15.3)

Comment: There is no such thing as a ["psql database"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). psql is the command-line terminal of Postgres (with it's own version number). Please clarify.

Comment: Hi Erwin , 

I got the posted errors above when i am trying to start my psql/postgresql database using this command: sudo systemctl restart postgresql-15
---- Error started occurring when i am trying to enable pgaudit, by adding/un-commenting this entry from the postgresql.conf:
# - Shared Library Preloading -
#shared_preload_libraries = 'pgaudit'   # (change requires restart)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first error `could not access file "pgaudit": No such file or directory` looks like you haven't installed `pgaudit`, but i see in the second snippet you have the right `pgaudit` version for your database version PostgreSQL 15.

I recommend you uninstall the current `pgaudit` and try installing it directly from [the source code here](https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit/releases).

Also ensure they are no errors in your `postgresql.conf` file.

Also, if you are using Greenplum, there is known compatibility issues with [`pgaudit` not supported until Greenplum 6.25.x and above.](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/FATAL-58P01-could-not-access-file-pgaudit-No-such-file-or-directory?language=en_US)

In addition, you can check out this detailed [article on auditing a PostgreSQL DB](https://severalnines.com/blog/how-to-audit-postgresql-database/). (Disclosure: I am affiliated with this site.)

Comment: Hi @Kiki,

Appreciated your inputs, as per your advise we have our sysad reinstalled pgaudit, and no we are not using greenplum.
We also downloaded pgAudit 1.7.0 (PostgreSQL 15) from the provided link.

pgaudit reinstalled using this command: rpm -iv pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90110+d8a562d5.x86_64.rpm --nodes

However we got the same error, still pgaudit cannot be read.

Comment: Somewhere on the installation of pgaudit, we surely are missing and doing something wrong.
Please advise what went wrong on our installation of pgaudit for OEL platform, are we using the righ command to install pgaudit's rpms?
Do we need to directly install the rpm inside the extracted directory of pgAudit 1.7.0 files that we downloaded?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Dave

Comment: [root@pgaudit-1.7.0]# locate pgaudit
/home/pamsad/pgaudit-1.5.0-1.module+el8.4.0+20016+06fd4df3.x86_64.rpm
/home/pamsad/pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.9.0+90110+d8a562d5.x86_64.rpm
/usr/lib64/pgsql/pgaudit.so
/usr/share/doc/pgaudit
/usr/share/doc/pgaudit/README.md
/usr/share/licenses/pgaudit
/usr/share/licenses/pgaudit/LICENSE
/usr/share/pgsql/extension/pgaudit--1.7.sql
/usr/share/pgsql/extension/pgaudit.control

Comment: So sorry about this Dave. What do you think about trying a different package manager? .... Clean up your current installation and try installing with `dnf`

See these links below. 

https://oraclelinux.pkgs.org/8/ol8-appstream-x86_64/pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.8.0+20973+992b6275.x86_64.rpm.html

https://linux-packages.com/oracle-linux-8/package/pgauditsrc

Comment: @DaveB, if that doesn't work, you can try using this tool called [ClusterControl](https://severalnines.com/clustercontrol/) it has a free forever community Version, and you can easily set it up for your DB. 

So instead of all the hassle you will just set up `pgaudit` with its CLI using this command:

`$ s9s cluster --setup-audit-logging --cluster-id=ID`... it does all the setup for your from adding it to `preload_libaries` to restarting.

Comment: Hi @Kiki, thanks again for your time to look into my issue. I have tried to remove the recent package installed and clean-up my previous installation.. We tried using the package you provided on the link but we got an error (will post the error on next comment, i couldn't get the formatting here):

Comment: warning: pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.8.0+20973+992b6275.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ad986da3: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        postgresql-server(:MODULE_COMPAT_15) is needed by pgaudit-1.7.0-1.module+el8.8.0+20973+992b6275.x86_64

Comment: The error posted above, upon trying the package. This is what i found recently, our platform is on OEL, however the installed packages of our postgresql DB is on RHEL, so i am installing the wrong pgaudit package all along? Is there a specific pgaudit installer for RHEL? The package above was for OEL. Will post on another comment the installed packages of our postgresql ver 15.3

Comment: Last metadata expiration check: 2:13:34 ago on Wed 24 Jan 2024 06:42:17 AM PST.
Installed Packages
postgresql15.x86_64                                                      15.3-2PGDG.rhel8                                                       @@commandline

Comment: Nice Glad you where able to resolve this Dave.

Comment: It turns out to be a simple solution, for starters on postgre like me, your inputs are much appreciated! thanks again @Kiki!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. We only just need to download the correct rpms/package for pgaudit, i've noticed late that the installed postgresql15 was using 2GPGDG.rhel8 and not OEL. This is the correct package for RHEL8 pgaudit17_15-1.7.0-1.rhel8.x86_64.rpm. Thanks to @Kiki and @Erwin for the inputs.